# Textbox Text change Event

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a form and I am want to call a stored procedure on text change event of that text-box ,
Can you suggest any idea.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What technology are you using to write your form? Is it WebForms? MVC? Just HTML?

Comment: You can write service (WCF or legacy service) method and request it through JavaScript (jQuery) AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to handle the [`TextChanged`-event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
             OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    TextBox txt = (TextBox) sender;
    // call your stored-procedure
}
```

Note that you should databind the controls only `if(!IsPostBack)`, otherwise the events are not triggered. So for example in `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataBindForm();  // which sets the `Text` property of this TextBox among others
    }
}
```